# How to show that sum is upper bounded by integral

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to prove a statement about an upper bound of a numerical scheme, or recursion, and I need help showing an intermediate result, namely that the sum below is upper bounded by the integral:

$$\Delta t \sum_{\nu = 0}^{n-1}e^{\alpha(t_{n}-t_{\nu+1})} \leq \int_{0}^{t_{n}}e^{\alpha(t_{n}-s)}ds.$$

Now, I have seen that sums of decreasing functions are upper bounded by their corresponding integral version, but how do I go from sum to integral like this? I do not really understand the significance of $\Delta t$ also. Could someone give me a hint/explain how to argue here?

Best regards//

**Edit 1** Has there something to do with using right Riemann sums for decreasing functions like this to show the inequality holds?

**Edit 2** $\alpha$ is a scalar constant.

Comment: Yes, this is simply a Riemann sum, where $e^{\alpha(t_{n}-t_{\nu})}=\inf_{s\in[t_\nu,t_{\nu+1}]}e^{\alpha(t_{n}-s)}$ (Whether this is true, however, depends a bit on $\alpha$)

Comment: Ok, how does it depend on $\alpha$? I forgot to mention that $\alpha$ does not depend on $\Delta t$ or $t_{n}-t_{\nu}$ if this changes anything.

Comment: Since $t_{n}$ increases with increasing $n$, does your identity really hold? Should it not be $e^{\alpha(t_{n}-t_{\nu})}=\inf_{s\in[t_{\nu-1},t_{\nu}]}e^{\alpha(t_{n}-s)}$? @HagenvonEitzen